# Reload UITableView Data without reloading the view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView` that contains a bunch of items whose status I get from a web app each time the table loads via a method `refreshRows`. After I do this I reload the table.

When I added an item to my table, I found myself getting a message “Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section”. Reloading the data in the table turned out to be necessary, so I made the change from the old to the new `viewDidAppear` methods (both shown below). I now have two `reloadData` calls, which both refresh my view.

QUESTION: Is there a cleaner way to do this? After an add I need to reload my data, but I'd prefer not to reload the view until all the statuses from the web are fetched.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated // new
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData]; // <------------- Prettier way to do this?
    [self refreshRows];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated // old
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self refreshRows];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)refreshRows {
    // foreach row get status from webapp
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the requested code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
    [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: can you post you numberOfRowsInSection method? Are you adding items to the table using insertRowsAtIndexPaths? the error you mentioned is usually caused when you're calling the tableView insert method without updating your model.

Comment: that's what is happening... but there is a way to reload the model without reloading the view?

Answer (score 4):

You might try to do this way, if only your data source know about the changes (and should observe that point):

1. Register your TableView to observe notification center for dataSource updates.
2. Post a notification from datasource to NSNotificationCenter that update had come.
3. React for the update in TableView with [self.tableView reloadData];

In the data source:

```
- (void) dataSourceChanged
{

    // All instances of TestClass will be notified
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"myUniqueDataSourceChanged" 
        object:self];

}
```

In Table View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated // new
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData]; // <------------- Prettier way to do this?
    [self refreshRows];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"myUniqueDataSourceChanged"
        object:self.dataSource];
}

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"myUniqueDataSourceChanged"])
        [self dataSourceHasBeenChanged];
}

- (void) dataSourceHasBeenChanged
{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self refreshRows];
}
```

This will update your Table View on every update of datasource automatically